# Finding Nerode equivalence classes of non regular languages

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations, formal-languages

I am trying to understand how to find equivalence classes for this non-regular language but I cannot really understand it.
$$
L= \{ c^nw \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\space \text{and}\space w \in \{ a, b \}^* \space \text{and}\space |w| = n \}
$$
Can someone guide on what to think or consider to solve this? What is the best approach to determine the equivalence classes of a non-regular language, e.g. for the language above? How would you proceed?

Comment: Is it $L = \{ c^n w \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \wedge w \in \{a,b\}^n\}$?  As you wrote it, if I read it correctly, $|w|$ must be $1$.

Comment: can you elaborate on why |w| must be 1?

Comment: Because $w \in \{a,b\}$ means that $w$ is either $a$ or $b$.  The length is $1$ in both cases.  You could say $w \in \{a,b\}^n$, or $w \in \{a,b\}^* \wedge |w|=n$, but as you wrote it is probably wrong.

Comment: OK. Thanks.  What does it mean, intuitively, for two words to be in the same equivalence class w.r.t. a language $L$?  Can $cc$ and $ccc$ be in the same equivalence class?

Comment: Said otherwise: suppose you have a word starting with $cc$ that is in $L$.  Perhaps, $ccab$.  What happens if you replace $cc$ with $ccc$.  Is the new word still in $L$?

Comment: no, because how I understood it, if you add an alphabet, for example, a to c and cc, c would be in the language but cc wouldn't. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, $ca$ is in $L$, but $cca$ isn't.  This is what it means for $c$ and $cc$ not to be equivalent.  Now, how many different equivalent classes are there?

Comment: I suppose infinite?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, and that is the same as saying that $L$ is not regular.

Comment: Well, my task says I should give all the Myhill-Nerode-Relation classes of L. I was able to determine the classes for a regular language but is there any way to at least categorize the classes for a non-regular language?

Comment: Yes, I'm writing that up as an answer, but you may start thinking about which words in $\{a,b,c\}$ are in the same equivalence class.  Of course, you are not going to list them all one by one, but what about $cccab$ and $cca$?  Is there a $u$ you can append to both such that $cccabu$ is accepted and $ccau$ is rejected or vice versa?

Comment: alright, thank you for your time!

Comment: Why do you want to compute the Myhill-Nerode-Relation classes of $L$?To prove that $L$ is not regular, it is much easier to observe that its intersection with the regular language $c^*a^*$ is $\{c^na^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, a language that you probably already know not to be regular.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Sigma$ be a finite alphabet and let $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ be a language.  In our case, $\Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$ and

$$ L = \{ c^nw \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \wedge w \in \{a,b\}^* \wedge |w|=n\} \enspace. $$

Two words $u$ and $v$ in $\Sigma^*$ are equivalent w.r.t. $L$ if, for all words $z \in \Sigma^*$, $uz \in L$ if and only if $vz \in L$.  Said otherwise, two words are equivalent if adding the same suffix to both results in two words that are either both in $L$ or both not in $L$.

A finite automaton accepts an infinite language, one containing infinitely many words, precisely when $\Sigma^*$ is divided into finitely many equivalence classes.  Each class then corresponds to one state of the minimal DFA accepting $L$.

---

For our $L$, words that don't have all their $c$'s before the $a$'s and $b$'s are irrecoverable: there is no way to extend a word like $cac$ to a word in $L$.  All these words are in the same equivalence class, which contains also irrecoverable words like $ccaaa$.

A word that contains no $a$ or $b$ (it is $c^n$ for some $n$) cannot be in the same class as any other word.  (Can you find an extension that proves it?)

For words of the form $c^nu$, with $u \in \{a,b\}^m$ and $1 \leq m \leq n$, what matters is $n-m$; hence each nonnegative value of $n-m$ gives a different equivalence class.  (How would you describe the class corresponding to $m=n$?)

Clearly our $L$ is not regular because there is no upper bound on $n$.